# Concatenating vue API URL

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm trying to connect an API to my Vue app, but can't seem to get it to work properly.

Checking dev tools, it looks like the app is making the request using only "https://api.scryfall.com/cards/search?q=!" and not including the part of the string that was concatenated.

Any ideas? The URL should include some kind of card name at the end.

`App.vue`

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <deckBuilder @addCard="addCard" @clearDeck="clearDeck" @requestData="requestData"
      :title="title" :card="card" :deck="deck" :received="received" />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import deckBuilder from './components/deckBuilder';
import axios from 'axios';

const apiLink = "https://api.scryfall.com/cards/search?q=!";

export default {
  name: 'app',
  components: {
    deckBuilder,
  },
  data: () => ({
    title: 'MTG Deck Builder',
    card: '',
    deck:[],
    received: {},
    errors: {},
    url: apiLink + this.card,
  }),
  methods: {
    addCard: function(cardName) {
      this.deck.push(cardName);
      this.card = '';
    },
    clearDeck: function(deck) {
      this.deck = [];
    },
    requestData: function() {
      console.log("Fetching Data from " + this.url)
      return (axios.get('')
      .then(response => {
        this.received = response.data;
        return this.received;
      }))


/*      .catch(err => {
        this.errors = err.response.data;
        console.log("Error!");
        console.log(errors);
      }));
*/

    },
  },
}
</script>

<style>

</style>
```

deckBuilder.vue

```
<template>
  <div>
    <h1>{{ title }}</h1>
    <input @keyup.enter="addCard" v-model="card" placeholder="Type a Card Name" />
    <button @click="addCard">Add!</button>
    <button @click="clearDeck">Clear Deck</button>
    <button @click="requestData">Request</button>
    <br>
    <h2>Deck: {{ deck.length }} Cards</h2>
    <ul>
      <li v-for="item in deck">{{ item }}</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'deckBuilder',
  props: ['title', 'card', 'deck', 'errors', 'received',],
  methods: {
    addCard() {
      this.$emit('addCard', this.card);
    },
    clearDeck() {
      this.$emit('clearDeck', this.deck);
    },
    requestData(){
      this.$emit('requestData', this.card);
    },
  },
}
</script>

<style scoped>

</style>
```

Comment: I guess that `this.card` is empty, and it's why you are getting this problem.

Comment: In your `addCard` method why are you initialising this.card

Comment: I was clearing the data in addCard. I removed that line and it still has this.card as undefined.

Comment: Don't remove that line just change `this.card = cardName;`

Comment: I added that and it's still setting the url as "https://api.scryfall.com/cards/search?q=!undefined" instead of "https://api.scryfall.com/cards/search?q=!opt" for example.

Comment: You shouldn't use v-model on a prop, you should use an event to emit updates to the card and your url should be a computed property so that it tracks changes of the card value.

Comment: Well, you initialize `this.card` to be an empty string and nowhere in the code shown do you set it to any other value. Why would you expect the URL to have any value other than an empty string?

Answer (score 0):

According to your demo code,

```
addCard: function(cardName) {
      this.deck.push(cardName);
      this.card = '';
    },
```

I think you get confused, the `cardName` was inserted to `deck` by event rather than `card`,
and you set an empty string with `this.card` which means the card is empty on next line, so you can't get any string once you apply `addCard`.

please try to use `url: apiLink + this.deck[0],` to replace `url: apiLink + this.card,`